# How to create a user defined function in sybase?

Tags: user-defined-functions, sap-ase

I trying to define a function in sybase. I write this script:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserGroup (userId int)
RETURNS int
BEGIN
    RETURN (10)
END
```

but when I run this, I get this error:

```
>[Error] Script lines: 1-6 --------------------------
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
 Msg: 156, Level: 15, State: 2
 Server: NEWSERVER, Procedure: GetUserGroup, Line: 3 

>[Error] Script lines: 1-6 --------------------------
 A RETURN statement with a return status may only be used in a SQL stored procedure.
 Msg: 178, Level: 15, State: 1
 Server: NEWSERVER, Procedure: GetUserGroup, Line: 4 

 [Executed: 10/13/09 11:01:29 AM IRST ] [Execution: 0/ms]
```

What can I do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I searched very much in web and other documents, I find that user-defined functions in Adaptive Server Enterprise 12 (ASE) must be implemented in Java.
I decided to use a StordProcedure. It usage is a little hard but it supported in all version of Sybase.

see: http://www.sypron.nl/udf.html

Answer (score 1):

I doesn't find any thing wrong with the code. you can re-try with the code below-

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserGroup (userId int)
RETURNS int
As
BEGIN
    RETURN (10)
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This ....it will work

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserGroup (@userId int)
RETURNS int
As
BEGIN
declare @Result int
select @Result=10
RETURN @Result
END
```

Answer (score -1):

this worked for me.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetUserGroup (@userId int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
 select @userId = 10
    RETURN @userId
END
```